# Resources Folder doesn't exist in my maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to create a Maven project with Eclipse.
I need to put my hibernate configuration file in a Folder named Resources. Which is supposed to exist in src/main/Resources. I can't find it and I don't know how to create it.

I used the webapp-javaee6 Archetype.

Should I use another Archetype ? Create my folder manually ?

Comment: Just create it manually.

Comment: And the name is `resources` and not `Resources`.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid creating it wouldn't be enough. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The name of your directory is incorrect. It should be in lowercase `src/main/resources`. Maven is case sensitive.
- If the directory does not exist, simply create it.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you could create a new simple Maven projet checking the box with "skip archetype selection".

Anyway, you also can try right clicking your project in Project Explorer > Maven > Update project configuration. This create missing (re)source folders.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Configure build path of your Project.
Under Source tab add folder `resources`

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the project or just create one by yourself